# Writing float values to .csv file

Tags: c++, excel, csv

I have a little problem with the formatting in Excel
I'm trying to write some floating values into a .csv file and view it with Microsoft Excel.
For example I write 6.21 and 12.42 in the first line. Then excel makes Jun 21 and Dec 46 out of it. Or it makes 124199 out of a 124.199.

```
[...]
    fstream f;
    f.open("test.csv", ios::out);
    for(i=0; i<world1->GetTime(); i++)
    f << Values[i][0] << ';' << Values[i][1] << endl;
    f.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What does the raw text say?

Comment: `6.21` I'd suspect Excel expects `6,21` to identify it as a floating point value. How `float` and `double` values are rendered depends on your actual [`locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) settings.

Comment: @user3662357 To clarify what I've been suspecting, you could first experiment with changing and trimming the `.csv` until Excel accepts the values correctly on import. If you have that, you'll check how you can [format the `float` and `double` values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) that they reproduce your working `.csv` template. That's the best advice I can give now, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not have anything to do with your code - it is the Excel settings that you should modify in order to display your results correctly (OK, you could modify your code, but it is much simpler to do it via Excel).

One of the most common source of errors while trying to display .csv files in Excel is the fact that Excel in some languages uses commas as decimal separators, while C++ uses dots. Depending on your Excel version, you can change your default decimal separator:
https://www.google.com/#q=excel+dot+as+decimal+separator.

Also, you can just select all the cells and search and replace dots with commas (ctrl + H). Another way that might work is selecting all the cells, then right-clicking them, selecting the 'Format cells' option and choosing the correct cell format (might help if the program still treats your values e.g. as dates even though you did what I have written above).