# Getting slack value in callback using the CPLEX C++ API

Tags: c++, cplex

I need to get the slack values of the constraints in my problem at each node of the exploration tree. To this end, I am thinking of using an [IloUserCutCallbackI](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex_UserCutCallbackI.html). According to the CPLEX documentation, the [getSlack](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex_ControlCallbackI.html#method_getSlack) method would be used for this purpose. I'd like to know if this is the right strategy. If so, I'm not sure how to pass an `IloRange` to my callback. Here is what I have so far:

```
ILOUSERCUTCALLBACK1(MyCallback,IloRange, con) {
cout << "slack" << getSlack << endl;
}
//define constraints
IloRange constraints;
.
.
.
cplex.use(MyCallback(env,constraints));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can query the slacks using the strategy you suggested. The `iloadmipex5.cpp` example that is included when you install CPLEX shows how to use a user cut callback. As with that example, it sounds like you'll want to pass an `IloRangeArray` to the callback rather than an `IloRange`.

For example, your callback might look like this:

```
ILOUSERCUTCALLBACK1(MyCallback, IloRangeArray, constraints) {
   for (IloInt i = 0; i < constraints.getSize(); ++i) {
      IloRange& con = constraints[i];
      IloNum const slack = getSlack(con);
      cout << "Slack for " << con << " = " << slack << endl;
   }
}
```

And, you would add the callback to your model, like so:

```
IloModel model(env);
IloRangeArray constraints(env);
// Add constraints to the array with constraints.add(...);
// Also, make sure that you have added the constraints to the model.
model.add(constraints);
IloCplex cplex(model);
cplex.use(MyCallback(env, constraints));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I want to export the value of slacks with node and the number of constraints to text or CSV file. I must use this link?https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=3fd44d41-210b-4b81-a005-819530d6377b&ps=25

Comment: That link is for OPL, but yes, that is the general idea. Instead of printing the slack value (as in my example above), you can dump it to a text file instead.

Comment: Is there any documentation for CPLEX concert C++?

Comment: There is no function in the CPLEX C++ API to export to CSV format. You'll have to do this yourself (as demonstrated in the link you provided) or use some third party library. This is a pure C++ question, not related to CPLEX, and has very little to do with your original question. Perhaps, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792652) stackoverflow thread or submit a new question.